# Sync down/up multiple soups in one go using SmartSync

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, smartstore, smartsync

Suppose i want to pull down `Account` and `Contact` records.

It seems (after reading the documentation and samples) that i have to create separate soup specs (e.g. in `userstore.json`) and the for each of those create a separate sync, and sync them sequentially.

This means that i want to pull down, say, 10-20 lists of objects of a few thousand each, the process could be quite error prone to get to the full clean slate.

Is it possible to join multiple soups so that a sync atomically succeeds or fails for all entities in one go?

I am on iOS Native, Swift, using mobile SDK 7.0

Answer (score -1):

You can pull/push related objects in one go by using a ParentChildrenSyncDownTarget/ParentChildrenSyncUpTarget.

For more information see: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/entity_framework_sync_related.htm

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Wolfgang! As mentioned on github, this works only for that specific scenario, once you have a multi-level tree, the SDK leaves a bit to be desired. https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS/issues/2835

I have since thought of a process that can greatly simplify things but that needs access to the FMDB which is not exposed, so i am currently using a fork of an SDK :)